# How to apply pipe (regex OR) to a specific substring of pattern so that it matches groups followed by EITHER a set of characters OR EOL?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string of questions and answers, which I want to split question-wise.

```
s = 'Q1 blah1 Ans BLAH1 Q2 blah2 Ans BLAH2'
re.split('(Q\d.*?)Q\d', s)
```

The result:

```
['', 'Q1 blah1 Ans BLAH1 ', ' blah2 Ans BLAH2']
```

I want to capture the portion which starts with 'Q#' and is followed by either another 'Q#' or the end of the line. So I tried using this:

```
re.split('(Q\d.*?)Q\d|$', s)
['', 'Q1 blah1 Ans BLAH1 ', ' blah2 Ans BLAH2']
```

and this:

```
re.split('(Q\d.*?)(Q\d|$)', s)
['', 'Q1 blah1 Ans BLAH1 ', 'Q2', ' blah2 Ans BLAH2']
```

But, they don't give me the desired results. It doesn't work in the first case because of improper usage of `|`, but I don't know how to rectify it. In the second case, the `Q2` doesn't get captured along with `blah2 Ans BLAH2`.

**EDIT:**

Desired output:

```
['', 'Q1 blah1 Ans BLAH1 ', 'Q2 blah2 Ans BLAH2']
```

Comment: Can you add the desired output also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try splitting on the following pattern:

```
\s+(?=Q\d+)
```

This uses a positive lookahead assertion which asserts, but does not consume, that the next question is starting.

```
s = 'Q1 blah1 Ans BLAH1 Q2 blah2 Ans BLAH2'
print re.split('\s+(?=Q\d+)', s)

['Q1 blah1 Ans BLAH1', 'Q2 blah2 Ans BLAH2']
```

### Demo

Comment: Yeah, I'd already done it. I'm familiar with the practices here at SE. Anyway, it kept saying I couldn't accept an answer within 5 minutes.