# get text in between multiple flags using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

i have the following text :

> 1. The first Heading  This is heading 1 data
> 2. The second header : this is heading 2 data
> 3. third header this is heading 3 data

So, i am trying to write a single regex. i know for a fact that to extract data between heading 1 and heading 2, the following regex will work

```
The first Heading(.*?)The second header
```

The above will give the text "This is heading 1 data".
But, what i am trying to get is to look for all the heading's that is a regex, which will return  a list as follows

```
["This is heading 1 data","This is heading 2 data","This is heading 3 data"]
```

What i had in mind was the following

```
The first Heading(.*?)The second header(.*?)third header (.*?)
```

But, i am not getting any data for the above regex. can anyone help me with the solution

Comment: Use the `DOTALL` mode as you have linebreaks (at least in your sample).

Comment: Try [`re.findall(r'^\s*Heading\s*\d+(?:\s*:)?\s*(.+)', s, re.M | re.I)`](http://rextester.com/JRGK56319). Note that `(.*?)` at the end of the pattern will always match an empty string whatever the flags are used.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, here i just mentioned Heading 1 to make it easier to understand. But, actually, each heading  is actual text like, Introduction, Table of content, Section 1. so, how would i do if each heading is different and i have each heading data

Comment: @Jan, its not about different lines, i am trying to get text in between each pair of headings. do you think this is possible

Comment: @Kalyan Regex is about matching patterns of text. What is the heading *pattern*? If you cannot define it, you can hardly devise a reliable regex pattern to match it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i have the list of headings. so, what i wanted was to get all the text between each of the pair of the headings. I know that i can do it by taking a pair of headings and get the text between them. But, i was looking into the possibility, if i could get all the text between all the heading pairs using a single regex expression

Comment: There was a similar question today. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50206391/3832970. Basically, you may use [`re.split(r'[\r\n]+(?:{})(?:\s*:)?\s*'.format('|'.join(my_heading_list)), s)`](http://rextester.com/PBZXP97648)

Comment: Does that work for you? Please post the list of headings you have. Or can there be arbitrary texts in between/before/after the headings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170526/discussion-between-kalyan-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: Please compile the list of known headings, and use them with the code I suggested above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import re

a = '''Heading 1 This is heading 1 data
Heading 2 This is heading 2 data
Heading 3 This is heading 3 data'''

print(re.findall('(?<=Heading \d\s)(.*)(?:Heading \d|$)?', a)))
#['This is heading 1 data', 'This is heading 2 data', 'This is heading 3 data']
```